# Filter joined rows if column's value exists in another table

Tags: mysql, join

Today I have encountered a problem as follows (fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b5cff7fb81fbe0ddd077a67629c56b05)):

```
create table ta02 
(
  t_key      varchar(255) default null,
  ta_over_amount decimal(13,2) default null,
  name           varchar(255) default null
);
```

and:

```
create table voucher 
(
  v_key       varchar(255) default null,
  over_amount decimal(13,2) default null,
  signature   varchar(255) default null
);
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO ta02 (t_key, ta_over_amount, name) VALUES ('gogo', 100.00, 'anh');
INSERT INTO ta02 (t_key, ta_over_amount, name) VALUES ('gogo', 50.00, 'duc');
INSERT INTO ta02 (t_key, ta_over_amount, name) VALUES ('logbasex', 25.00, 'ho');
INSERT INTO ta02 (t_key, ta_over_amount, name) VALUES ('logbasex', 15.00, 'phi');
```

and:

```
INSERT INTO voucher (v_key, over_amount, signature) VALUES ('gogo', 100.00, 'blue');
INSERT INTO voucher (v_key, over_amount, signature) VALUES ('gogo', 50.00, 'white');
INSERT INTO voucher (v_key, over_amount, signature) VALUES ('logbasex', 14.00, 'itsme');
INSERT INTO voucher (v_key, over_amount, signature) VALUES ('logbasex', 25.00, 'green');
```

This is my join query without any conditions:

```
select t.name, t.ta_over_amount, v.over_amount, v.signature 
from ta02 t 
left join voucher v on t.t_key = v.v_key;
```

Result:

```
name    ta_over_amount  over_amount     signature
anh     100.00           50.00          white
anh     100.00          100.00          blue
duc     50.00            50.00          white
duc     50.00           100.00          blue
ho      25.00            25.00          green
ho      25.00            15.00          itsme
phi     15.00            25.00          green
phi     15.00            14.00          itsme
```

And the required condition is:

- On the same `v_key`, only join which row that has `ta_over_amount` value does not equal to corresponding `over_amount` value of matched row and the list `ta_over_amount` values (get by the joined key `v_key` in `ta02` table) does not contains `over_amount` value.
- For example, when joining two tables with `v_key` = `gogo` (first row) in `ta02` table, that will match two corresponding rows in `voucher` table, which is include `signature` = **blue** and **white** respectively. With a row has `signature` = **blue**, the `over_amount` value = 100 is equals to the `ta_over_amount` value then I ignore that row (clearly doesn't satify my condition), with a row has `signature` = **white**, the `over_amount` value = 50 is not equals to `ta_over_amount` but exits in list of `ta_over_amount` values with `v_key` = `gogo` in `ta02` table then I also need to ignore this row.

And this is my desired result:

```
    +----+--------------+-----------+---------+
    |name|ta_over_amount|over_amount|signature|
    +----+--------------+-----------+---------+
    |phi |15.00         |14.00      |itsme    |
    +----+--------------+-----------+---------+
```

- Ex:

```
ta02 table                                
+--------+--------------+----+
|key     |ta_over_amount|name|
+--------+--------------+----+
|gogo    |100.00        |anh |
|gogo    |50.00         |duc |
|logbasex|25.00         |ho  |
|logbasex|15.00         |phi |
+--------+--------------+----+

voucher table
+--------+-----------+---------+
|key     |over_amount|signature|
+--------+-----------+---------+
|gogo    |110.00     |blue     |
|gogo    |50.00      |white    |
|logbasex|25.00      |itsme    |
|logbasex|15.00      |green    |
+--------+-----------+---------+

My expected result is:
+----+--------------+-----------+---------+
|name|ta_over_amount|over_amount|signature|
+----+--------------+-----------+---------+
|anh |100.00        |110.00     |blue     |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------+

- 100 doesn't match 110, I include this one in the desired result.
- 100 doesn't match 50, but 50 exits in ta_over_amount list, ignore
- 50  doesn't match 110, but 50 exits in over_amount list, ignore
- 50 match 50, ignore
```

Comment: And what if there are 15,16,17 in one table and 14,13 in the other so 3 and 2 mismatching rows respectively? Do you expect 6 rows in the result? Or something else? And what if there are 5 rows with 100 in one and 2 rows with 100 in the other? What should happen then? Please define behaviour for these cases. And what if there are nulls?...

Comment: select t.name, t.ta_over_amount, v.over_amount, v.signature 
from ta02 t 
left join voucher v on t.t_key = v.v_key
WHERE t.ta_over_amount > v.over_amount; result: name  ta_over_amount  over_amount  signature
anh  100.00  50.00  white
phi  15.00  14.00  itsme
ho  25.00  14.00  itsme - you need more joining info

Comment: Basically I want to remove duplicate rơw after join based on `ta_over_amount` value and `over_amount value` include permutation cases.

Comment: assuming `voucher` table always has more rows than `ta02` table, if `v_key` are the same and the list `ta_over_amount` doesn't contains `over_amount` value in `voucher` table, ignore it. And what if there are 5 rows with 100 in one and 2 rows with 100 in the other? In this case, nothing needs to return. Both tables doesn't' allow to contains `null` @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: Maybe [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f1051ac8430dad0827cb2e3b6207314) will explain why what you're asking is impossible without more fields to join on... how can we choose which records to include or not include based on the information you have given? It's impossible at the moment...